# Why Eclipse Pydev uses @author in default template

Tags: eclipse, templates, pydev, restructuredtext, docstring

I have been intrested for python documenting for a while but I can't figured out why @author is default sytnax in python templates. Why it isn't :author: (in restructuredtext style)?

From what reason is used syntax with @ and not with :

I though that restructuredtext is most common in python world.

Comment: Is this question about the markup language used, or specifically the `@author` directive?

Comment: I edited the question. Maybe is more specific now. It is wierd to me that restructuredtext is most common but in template is used another style. I'm afraid I miss some important tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Epytext Markup language](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-epytext.html) is what you're looking for.  It is [epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/)'s language.

It makes use of the `@` prefix, with such words as `param`, `type`, `return`, `raise`, etc.

Comment: And epytext is so common that pydev has it like default template? And could it be something about svn or something?

Comment: Can you be more specific? what are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "could it be"...?

Comment: I thought that maybe svn uses this attributes but it's probably nonsens.

Comment: @Karlvonbahnhof you need to take a look on history - PyDev is older project than Sphinx and the documentation of Python code has been mixed bag before Sphinx kind of standardized it. Default Sphinx templates would make sense today. Fabio is great guy and surely accepts contributions to PyDev ;)

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer that I ecpected.