# Does anyone have experience to change pydev module template into reStructuredText markup type?

Tags: templates, pydev, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317141/why-eclipse-pydev-uses-author-in-default-template)'s a relevant question about pydev default module template.

As most of pydev users would know that, default module templates use epydoc-type markup style. However most of python codes use reStructuredText style and thus it is recommended to change module templates.

My question is 'Does anyone have experience to change pydev module template into reStructuredText markup type?' If you do, then would you mind sharing it? Properly used templates will save much time.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit templates in PyDev by going to:

`preferences > PyDev > editor > templates`

Then you can order them by context (click on the related column) and edit the ones that are under `New Module`.

Comment: Thank you sir, however what I ask is not how to change templates, but how you guys changed template files. That is I want some experts to share their default module templates for Pydev